# How to display only 7 days record in greendao android?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, greendao

I am inserting all datas and displaying in graph but how to display only last 7 days graph from greendao?

For eg:

1. If I start to insert data today. It should display only today's date.(say for eg: 22/07)
2. Then next day, It will insert data. (then I need to display 22/07, 23/07)
3. If my current date is 30/07, then I need to display(23/07,24/07/25/07 to till 30/07) neglecting other datas ie 22/07.

But I am getting all datas and displaying in my case. ie from 22/07 to 30/07. How to display only 7 days by deleting old one.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Here is my code which it's displaying all datas.

In DetectiveGraphExcecutor:

```
public List<DetectiveGraph> getDetectionsGraphBetweenTime(Date    fromDateAndTime, Date toTimeAndDate) {
    List<DetectiveGraph>  mTask = mDetectiveGraphDao.queryBuilder().where(DetectiveGraphDao.Properties.Detective_date.between(fromDateAndTime, toTimeAndDate)).list();
    closeSession();
    return mTask;
}

  public List<DetectiveGraph> getAllDetections() { //getting all datas
    return mDetectiveGraphDao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(DetectiveGraphDao.Properties.Detective_date).list();
}

 public class ActivityTracking extends Activity{
 private DetectiveGraphExecutor mDetectiveGraphExecutor;
 private List<DetectiveGraph> mDetectiveGraphList;
 private int columnIndex;
 private List<DetectiveGraph> activities; //The activities.
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //onCreate
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //super
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking);
 mDetectiveGraphList = mDetectiveGraphExecutor.getAllDetections(); 
 maxDate =  mDetectiveGraphList.get(mDetectiveGraphList.size()-1).getDetectiveDate();
 toDates = maxDate; // maximumDate
 Calendar toDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //toDateCalendar
   toDateCalendar.setTime(toDates); //toDateCalendar
 Calendar fromDateCalendar = (Calendar) toDateCalendar.clone();  
 fromDateCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -7); //fromDateCalendar
 fromDateCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)); //minute
                fromDateCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); //second
                Long initialLogTime = Long.valueOf(VALRTApplication.getPrefString(ActivityTracking.this, "epochTime"));
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //calendar
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(initialLogTime); //setTime
                calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)); //minute
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); //second
                Calendar fromDateTime = calendar; //fromDate
                columnIndex = -1; //columnIndex
                do {
                    Date fromDate = null, toDate = null; //fromDate
                    Calendar toDateTime = (Calendar) fromDateTime.clone(); //toDate
                    toDateTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 60); //toDateTime
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:aa"); //dateFormat
                    dateString = dateFormat.format(fromDateTime.getTime()); //dateString
                    dateString1 = dateFormat.format(toDateTime.getTime()); //dateString1
                    try {
                        fromDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString); //dateString
                        toDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString1);//toDate
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        LogUtils.e(VALRTApplication.TAG, e); //exceptional handling
                    }
                    if (fromDate != null && toDate != null) { //fromDate and to date not null
                        updateGraph(fromDate, toDate, entries, labels);
                    }
                    textName.setText(iAddedDate); //setText
                    fromDateTime.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1); //add
                }
                while (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() >= fromDateTime.getTimeInMillis()); //getTime
              }

    //in this I am updating graph based on the date and updating in UI. 

private void updateGraph(Date fromDate, Date toDate, List<BarEntry> entries, ArrayList<String> labels) {
    activities = mDetectiveGraphExecutor.getDetectionsGraphBetweenTime(fromDate, toDate); //getDetectionGraph
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormats = new SimpleDateFormat("h:aa"); //hour and am/pm
    SimpleDateFormat withDateTimes = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); //withDateTimes
    iAddedDate = withDateTimes.format(toDate.getTime()); //getTime
    String newDate = iAddedDate.substring(0, iAddedDate.length() - 5); //newDate
    String dateToTimes = dateFormats.format(toDate.getTime()); //getTime
    String replaceTime = dateToTimes.replaceAll(":", " ").toUpperCase(); //toUpperCase
    String outputDates = "\n" + newDate + "\n" + replaceTime; //replaceTime
    entries.add(new BarEntry(activities.size(), ++columnIndex)); //columnIndex
    labels.add(outputDates); //outputDates
    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, ""); //dataset
    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset); //data
    data.setDrawValues(false); //setDrawValues
    barChart.setData(data); //setData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, I think it would be easier to get from the database only the needed data. In order to do this, you should use something like that, assuming that `Detective_date` is a date type column.

```
Calendar toDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar fromDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()  
fromDateCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);

List<DetectiveGraph> filteredDetections = mDetectiveGraphDao.queryBuilder()
 .where(DetectiveGraphDao.Properties.Detective_date.ge(fromDateCalendar.getTime()),
        DetectiveGraphDao.Properties.Detective_date.le(toDateCalendar.getTime()))
 .orderAsc(DetectiveGraphDao.Properties.Detective_date)
 .list();
```